# multi part identifier can't be bound in an update query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to update a table with info from a different table using both tables as the condition

```
UPDATE prod
SET prod.sale=change.price
WHERE prod.sku=change.sku AND prod.isonsale=0;
```

Seems straight forward but I keep getting a multi part identifier can't be bound error, looking it up there's a lot of join statements flying about, but not a lot of explanation,  can someone tell me why this isn't working and maybe how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't included a table or table alias named `change` anywhere in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `change` table this way:

```
UPDATE
    prod
SET
    sale=change.price
FROM
    prod P
INNER JOIN
    change
ON 
    P.someid = change.someid
```

replace `someid` with a column name that would join the 2 tables.